# How can modify the wpf Expander so that the expander button is next to header text and center aligned and gets expanded down

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to customize my expander

I have a grid and one of the column is expander with header text before the expander button. And the expander should expand and fill the complete row as shown in the picture.

I couldn't post images so the link is below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVkpR.png

Can please somebody give me some thoughts how can I achieve this.

**Update:** 
I have used the control template and was able to modify as needed but struck with one thing how to make the expanded portion fill the entire row of the containing grid.

Here is the sample code:

```
<Window x:Class="ExpanderStyles.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ExpanderHeaderStyle"
            TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <Grid Background="Transparent"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="19"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="19"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Path x:Name="arrow" Grid.Column="1"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                        StrokeThickness="1.5"
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="false"
                                        Data="M 2,8 L 5.5,4.5 L 2,1">
                                    <Path.LayoutTransform>
                                        <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
                                    </Path.LayoutTransform>
                                </Path>
                                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0"
                                                Margin="0,4,0,0"
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                                SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                                                RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                                    Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Data"
                                    Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"
                                    TargetName="arrow"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="{x:Type Expander}"
            TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
                Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            CornerRadius="3"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="19"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                    <ToggleButton x:Name="HeaderSite"
                                            Margin="1"
                                            MinWidth="0"
                                            MinHeight="0"
                                            Style="{StaticResource ExpanderHeaderStyle}"
                                            IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                            Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                            ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplateSelector}"
                                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                            FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                                            FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                            FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}"
                                            FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}"
                                            FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"
                                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                                            VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Canvas>
                                <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ExpandSite"
                                                DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                                                Visibility="Collapsed"
                                                Focusable="false"
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">

                                </ContentPresenter>

                            </Grid>

                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsExpanded"
                                    Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility"
                                    Value="Visible"
                                    TargetName="ExpandSite"/>
                            </Trigger>

                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">Column 1</TextBlock>
        <Expander Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Header="Details" ExpandDirection="Left">
            <Grid Background="Blue">
                <TextBlock Text="Details content" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Foreground="White"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </Expander>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0">Column 3</TextBlock>



    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Any body has idea how to fill the parent grid row from control template?

Comment: This can be achieved using [ControlTemplates](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30994/Introduction-to-WPF-Templates)

Comment: I have gone through control templates but couldn't figure out how to make header text before the expander button and also make it center aligned

Comment: @MikeEason I have updated the question with a partial solution, Could you please help me to over come the problem I have mentioned Thanks!